# Ignore pkgs during initial bloom-release: master vs main branch

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As part of the release process for a new package, `bloom-release` will `git clone` the release repository and start adding branches and commits.

`bloom-release` seems to assume `master` is the default/main branch, and will create one if it doesn't exist.

For release repositories created on Github, and unless users have configured otherwise, new repositories will have their default branch set to `main` now instead of `master`.

This works OK for regular releases (as `master` will just be another branch to `git` and Github, and Bloom is able to find everything it needs just fine), but in case packages need to be *ignored* / *excluded* from an **initial** release, a `${ROS_DISTRO}.ignored` file should be added to the `master` branch, or Bloom will not find it (it creates a `master` branch and ignores `main` completely, including the `.ignored` file in it).

I've not been able to find a command line arg which lets me specify the branch Bloom should use for this.

Is there a way to do this, or should I be approaching this in a different way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368985/ignore-pkgs-during-initial-bloom-release:-master-vs-main-branch/) by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86574 on 2021-01-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is currently something that is hard-coded in Bloom: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/blob/master/bloom/config.py#L61
If you browse around in there you'll see some code which normalizes bloom's configuration to live on the bloom config branch. (before my time bloom's configuration lived on a `bloom` branch.)

Supporting other config branches, or if nothing else, reverting the config branch change so that we go back to using `bloom` is worthwhile but not something that I've got on any dedicated roadmap. No matter what we decide to hard code I'm sure that someone will find a complaint to make but I also can't think of a way to make it detectable that is completely robust with respect to temporary branches for pull request workflow changes to the bloom config branch.

---

Originally posted by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) with karma: 906 on 2021-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-07**:\

> I also can't think of a way to make it detectable that is completely robust

what about using the default branch?

I asked this question in the context of "rename `master` to `main`), and then running into the problem of Bloom not really working any more when you'd want to ignore certain packages.

I don't believe that'd need something which *always* works, as the context is pretty narrow:

- first time release
- 'empty' release repository
- `*.ignored` file in the repository

re: where to store configuration: [git notes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes) comes to mind, but I guess it's actually pretty convenient to track Bloom's configuration as a versionable artefact, and that's not what notes are for afaik.